# Convert month int to month name

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0

I was simply trying to use the `DateTime` structure to transform an integer between 1 and 12 into an abbrieviated month name.

Here is what I tried:

```
DateTime getMonth = DateTime.ParseExact(Month.ToString(), 
                       "M", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
return getMonth.ToString("MMM");
```

However I get a `FormatException` on the first line because the string is not a valid `DateTime`. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);
```

See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) for more details.

Or

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine( dt.ToString( "MMMM" ) );
```

Or if you want to get the culture-specific **abbreviated** name.

```
GetAbbreviatedMonthName(1);
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `GetAbbreviatedMonthName()` seems appropriate.

Comment: What is the opposite of this? input month name and get the number back?

Comment: `int month = DateTime.ParseExact(MonthNameValue, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month`

Comment: that's not int to month name, that's datetime to month name

Comment: Don't forget 'using System.Globalization'

Answer (score 40):

```
var monthIndex = 1;
return month = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(monthIndex);
```

You can try this one as well

Comment: Just to add something to this good answer, the DateTimeFormatInfo is inside of System.Globalization, then is needed to import this namespace.

Answer (score 15):

You can do something like this instead.

```
return new DateTime(2010, Month, 1).ToString("MMM");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(
    Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[7].Text.Substring(3,2))).Substring(0,3) 
    + "-" 
    + Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[7].Text).ToString("yyyy");
```

Comment: Where is `e` even coming from?!